# How do I subset and copy directories using a csv?

Tags: command-line, directory, cp, csv

How can I use .csv to copy and paste a specific set of directories to a new location?

.csv looks like this:

```
 directory-name
  500
  505
  666
  900
  .
  .
  .
  1200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xargs` with `cp` as following.

```
xargs -a /path/to/file.csv cp -r -t /path/to/dest/
```

Comment: But this won't allow me to subset and copy folders right?

Comment: this will copy all the folders are in _file.csv_ to target path, if you need exclude some, so you should exclude them using another list `grep -Fvf dont_copy.csv file.csv > should-copy.csv`; next use this answer to copy remained one's in _should-copy.csv_

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- The CSV file has a single column
- There is one folder name per line
- The first line is header and should be ignored

Then a loop like this should work:

```
tail -n +2 file.csv | while read dirname; do cp -r "$dirname" /path/to/target/; done
```

Notes:

- `tail -n +2` is to skip the first line of the file (output 2nd and later lines)
- The `while` loop reads folder names line by line, and for each line executes `cp -r`

Answer (score 1):

You can select a subset with [bash array slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815/how-to-slice-an-array-in-bash), using the next piece of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=(`tail -n +2 folders.csv`);
b=("${a[@]:$1:$2}");

for i in "${b[@]}"
do
    cp -r master_directory/"$i"/ new_path/;
done
```

This line`b=("${a[@]:$1:$2}");` lets you pass 2 arguments to your script and select only the folders between those arguments, for example if you type:

`$ bash script.sh 1 3`

the script would only select the folders between the line 1 and line 3 (after ignoring the header line). In your case it would select the 505, 666, 900 folders.

Comment: how can I specify the new_path without having to edit the script.sh over again?

Comment: @ChintanSheth you could always add paths and filenames and such as arguments; this is a little bit of a headache, but it *can* be done.

Comment: ok thanks @ThomasWard. This script is copying the contents of 505, but not creating a directory for it. But copies 666 and 900 in entirety.